# Setting Swift Date minutes with more than 60 returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Very new to IOS, I need to set a Date hour and minutes, I do like this:

```swift
let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: prayerTimeHour, minute: prayerTimeMinutes + Int(adjustement)! , second: 0, of: Date())!
```

`prayerTimeMinutes + Int(adjustement)!` in some cases are more than 60 so the app crash because the Date is `nil`

Comment: Swift is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the Calendar do all the math for you. There is no such time as "09:61" and Calendar is telling you so.

```
// It's not clear that you want the current calendar here. It may not be Gregorian.
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

// Using ! means you're promising prayerTimeHour and prayerTimeMinutes are valid.
let baseDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: prayerTimeHour,
                             minute: prayerTimeMinutes,
                             second: 0,
                             of: Date())!

// ! should be safe because the Gregorian calendar will have a date for any number
// of minutes into the future
let adjustedData = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute,
                                 value: adjustement,
                                 to: baseDate)!
```

Comment: Based on the fact that the OP is asking about handling prayer time, and his name is Mohammad, I'm guessing he's going to want to use the Islamic calendar rather than Gregorian. As far as I know time calculations like adding minutes work the same in both calendars though.

Comment: @DuncanC adding minutes to a Date IMO is fine as well regardless of the calendar. The main issue would be force unwrapping the result when setting a specific time (bySettingHour) which might not exist (i.e daylight savings transition date)